# PHP foreach code performance speed

Tags: php

I am trying to optimize increase the speed of this loop. I would like it if anyone has any ideas to boost the speed as there is thousands of members and it does take time time to complete currently

SQL Stored PROCEDURE MembersMobileByVenue returns this->
Example

```
FirstName Phone     Venue
Aaron   04*******   7272CD46D51F
Brad    04*******   CF105BB0
Adam    04*******   7272CD46D51F
Craig   04*******   CF105BB0
```

PHP

```
$venueIDS = isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : array();

$msg = $_POST['message'];
$response = array(); 

if(!empty($venueIDS)){
        $Members = GoldCardMembers::MembersMobileByVenue();
        foreach($Members as $Member){
            if(in_array($Member->Venue, $venueIDS)){
                $destination = $Member->Phone;
                $text = 'Hi ' . $Member->FirstName . ' ' .$msg. '. Reply STOP to opt out';
                $ref = 'Members';

                $content =  '&to='.rawurlencode($destination).
                            '&message='.rawurlencode($text).
                            '&ref='.rawurlencode($ref);

                $smsbroadcast_response = sendSMS($content);
                $response_lines = explode("\n", $smsbroadcast_response);

                 foreach( $response_lines as $data_line){
                    $message_data = "";
                    $message_data = explode(':',$data_line);
                    if($message_data[0] == "OK"){
                        array_push($response, "The message to ".$message_data[1]." was successful, with reference ".$message_data[2]."\n");
                    }elseif( $message_data[0] == "BAD" ){
                        array_push($response, "The message to ".$message_data[1]." was NOT successful. Reason: ".$message_data[2]."\n");
                    }elseif( $message_data[0] == "ERROR" ){
                        array_push($response, "There was an error with this request. Reason: ".$message_data[1]."\n");
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
}

foreach($response as $message){
    echo $message;
}
```

Comment: There are multiple `foreach()`'s in there. Including your `if/elseif/etc` which could cause issues. Right off the bat, you could change your `if/elseif/etc` to a `switch/case` statement. This will only provide marginal performance changes. What you should be doing is debugging & profiling your script to find the true bottleneck. It could be any of a few things, i.e. : your `GoldCardMembers::MembersMobileByVenue()`, `sendSMS()`, `if/elseif`, multiple `foreach()` calls. I'd suggest chunking your data and processing it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$venueIDS = isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : array();

$msg = $_POST['message'];

$text = "";
$destination = "";
$content = "";
$response_lines = array();
$smsbroadcast_response  = "";
$message_data = array();

if(!empty($venueIDS)){

        $Members = GoldCardMembers::MembersMobileByVenue();
        foreach($Members as $Member){ // O(n) size of $Members
            if(in_array($Member->Venue, $venueIDS)){ // O(v) size of $venueIDs

                $destination = rawurlencode($Member->Phone);
                $text = rawurlencode($Member->FirstName . ' ' .$msg);

                $content =  '&to='. $destination .
                            '&message=Hi ' . $text . '. Reply STOP to opt out'.
                            '&ref=Members';

                $smsbroadcast_response = sendSMS($content);
                $response_lines = explode("\n", $smsbroadcast_response); // O(r) number of "\n" occurances

                 foreach( $response_lines as $data_line){ // O(r)

                    $message_data = explode(':',$data_line); // O(d) number of ":" occurances

                    if($message_data[0] == "OK"){
                        echo "The message to ".$message_data[1]." was successful, with reference ".$message_data[2]."\n";
                    }elseif( $message_data[0] == "BAD" ){
                        echo "The message to ".$message_data[1]." was NOT successful. Reason: ".$message_data[2]."\n";
                    }elseif( $message_data[0] == "ERROR" ){
                        echo "There was an error with this request. Reason: ".$message_data[1]."\n";
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
}
```

Here's a list of what I did:

- removed the `for` loop from bottom and `echo` the `$message` directly from the main loop instead
- removed `$ref` var
- initialized `$destination`, `$text`, `$content`, `$response_lines`, `$smsbroadcast_response` and `$message_data` vars outside the `for` loop since declaring them inside the loop with each iteration is sub-optimal

That's all I can think about for now.

**Notes for further improvements:**

I'd investigate on the performance of `sendSMS` that you're using. It could be one of the components that are slowing things down.

In order to dig deeper, a helpful tool for analyzing performance is [big Oh notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). So I've added comments to label loop components.

Because we're looking at multiple nested loops we generally have something like O(N^3) here.

However, we could write that equation to be more detailed such as this:

O( n * (v + 2r) * d)

(please check code comments to see what each variable represents)

Since you're asking for a high "n" (number of members) I'd investigate ways to make the other variables like "v", "r" or "d" smaller.

Eliminating any of these variables altogether like removing

`$message_data = explode(':',$data_line);`

have the highest positive impact on performance (given that is still achieves the same functionality).